# How to scroll to a specific row in a specific page using material table ( react )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

What I want is on material table rendering , a particular row should be on the top , based on the index I provide .

Answer (score 0):

In a React component you'll need to create a reference, that will be pointing to the row later. `const ref = useRef(null);`

The ref should be assigned as an attribute to the specific row. `<tr ref={index === specificIndex && ref} />`

Now you can scroll to the page when it's rendered.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop);
}, []);
```

Comment: @Haris Ghori Did this answer your question?